# Working with emails

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm curious to know how to accomplish this task.

I have a function in my library that will send out an email. However it takes a parameter of $type and the type could be forgot password, successful registration, etc.

I want to be able to set parts of that type such as the subject of it as well as the message to be displayed for the different types of emails in one file to make it easier to edit down the line.

What kind of file should I create inside of codeigniter to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jeff,

Take a look at **Tank Auth**, they handle this sort of email thing already (its a small CI plugin/library for authentication, email password recovery, etc).

Just go through the code and pull out the email template you want, it comes in plain text and HTML flavor.

Proably the best way to always learn is to review other code.

Example from the **auth.php** controller (for reference):

```
/**
 * Send email message of given type (activate, forgot_password, etc.)
 *
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @param   array
 * @return  void
 */
function _send_email($type, $email, &$data)
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
    $this->email->reply_to($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject(sprintf($this->lang->line('auth_subject_'.$type), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth')));
    $this->email->message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-html', $data, TRUE));
    $this->email->set_alt_message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-txt', $data, TRUE));
    $this->email->send();
}
```

[Tank Auth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) is a good library, and easy to work with.

**EDIT**

> a **view** simply means generated output to a user, wether it is a
>   EMAIL or an HTML browser returned page doesn't matter.  the "text" you
>   speak of is a file reference `$type.'-txt'` is calling say
>   `$type="hello";` ==> `hello-txt` page in your view folder `/email
>
> also the **config** references are because **tank auth** has its own
>   config file in your `/apps/config/` folder the script references it
>   for things like **from** and **reply to**, also you see the
>   multi-lingual language support in
>   `$this->lang->line('auth_subject_'.$type)` which proably is not needed
>   for you.

Comment: Why do they have the text inside of a view instead of its own config file?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to create a config file for your mailer with the subjects and bodies of your email.

Load this config file in your mailing function.

The codeigniter user guide about config files has all the details about how to create config files: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

In a nutshell,

1. Create a new file in your application/config folder. call it mail_template
2. In that file add a config array with the stuff you need, for example

   `$config['templates']['lost_password']['subject'] = 'Lost Password';
   $config['templates']['lost_password']['body'] = 'The body';
   [...]`
3. In your mail function, load that file using `$this->config->load('mail_template', true);`
4. Access your variables using `$ templates = $this->config->item('templates', 'mail_template');`

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link for me that's more than just the link to the config file on the codeigniter's website of something that accomplishes this task that I can use as a template to look at?

Comment: @JeffDavidson Edited my answer with more details

Comment: Is there any benefit to using config files over views for this?

Comment: @JeffDavidson No benefit from a performance pov, but if you use html templates (views), you can pass them further variables from your controller taking andvantage of the dedicated mechanism of views, while configs are just static array indexes

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a series of views for each type (say in a folder called 'email_templates'), with variables where appropiate.
You could then use the view function to get the html, passing it into your email function (note third parameters that returns the html instead of rendering it.

```
$html = $this->load->view('email_templates/forgot_password', $data, TRUE);
```

Comment: Why are these stored in a view instead of just a config file?

Comment: @JeffDavidson because they are templates, i.e. views. Configs should be used as a way to _configurate_ something. It's a matter of logic (well, at least to me...), and if it's more within yours to use configs to store views, you're free to do it